# Caffe: Multi-Label Images with Varying Number of Labels

Tags: computer-vision, neural-network, hdf5, deep-learning, caffe

I have a dataset where the images have **VARYING** number of labels. The number of labels is between 1 and 5. There are 100 classes.

After googling, it seems like HDF5 db with slice layer can deal with multiple labels, as in the following [URL](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/caffe-users/james$20guo/caffe-users/_NdX1tpHt5Y/4A7ln18nr3YJ).

The only problem is that it supposes a fixed number of labels. Following this, I would have to create a 1x100 matrix, where entry value is 1 for the labeled classes, and 0 for non-label classes, as in the following definition:

```
layers {
  name: "slice0"
  type: SLICE
  bottom: "label"
  top: "label_matrix"
  slice_param {
      slice_dim: 1
      slice_point: 100
  }
}
```

where each image contains a a label looking like (1,0,0,...1,...0,....,0,1) where the vector size is 100 dimension.

Now, I apologize that my question becomes somehow vague, but is this a feasible idea? I.e., is there a better approach to this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I get that you have 5 types of labels that are not always present for each data point. 1 of the 5 labels is for 100-way classification. Correct so far?

I would suggest always writing all 5 labels into your HDF5 and use a special value for when the label is missing. You can then use the [missing_value](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/pull/1654) option to skip computing the loss for that layer for that iteration. Using it requires add `loss_param{ ignore_label = Y }` to the loss layer in your network prototxt definition where Y is a scalar.

The backpropagated error will only be a function of labels that are present. If input X does not have a valid value for a label, the network will still produce an estimate for that label. But it will not be penalized for it. The output is produced without any effect on how the weights are updated in that iteration. Only outputs for non-missing labels contribute to the error signal and the weight gradients.

It seems that only the Accuracy and SoftmaxWithLossLayer layers support missing_values.

Each label is a 1x5 matrix. The first entry can be for the 100-way classification (e.g. [0-99]) and entries 2:5 have scalars that reflect the values that the other labels can take. The order of the columns is the same for all entries in your dataset. A missing label is marked by a special value of your choosing. This special value has to lie outside the set of valid label values. This will depend on what those labels represent. If a label value of -1 never occurs you can use this to flag a missing label.

Comment: Are you suggesting the label for each image could be written as [5, 10, 25, 32, 91]? Regarding the PO's question, I'm only aware of the equivalent way of writing the label vector as a 100-dim vector with its 5th, 10th, 25th, 32nd and 91st as `1` and the remaining as `0`. May you provide any references? Thank you!

Comment: Sorry don't think I have references at the moment. You will either define your label vector as a long binary code and use the sigmoidcrossentropy loss layer. This will allow two classes in the label vector to be on at the same time or you define a loss layer for each 'type' of label. That way you can keep your scalar label values and not have to roll them out into a binary vector and concatenate them.